# PHP Calendar Foreach Loop Not Working as expected

Tags: php, foreach

Thanks for taking the time to review my question. I should preface with saying I'm not an expert PHP developer, but I know enough to be dangerous!

I'm currently working on setting up a PHP Calendar that displays 'events' if you will, on specific days.

I've modified the following code: http://www.codesend.com/view/84dba4acad5998d6fd4119c0c758dc52/

Currently, I'm able to get the foreach loop to go through the days and display the bootstrap modal box button on each of the days that data is present. When debugging using print_r & pre tags, I can see that the values are showing on each day correctly, but for some reason, it's duplicating my data across all the days, rather than putting each days data on the correct days.

I've tried doing an additional foreach loop within the current foreach loop, and that doesn't seem to work, or I'm not doing it correctly.

In the screenshot, you'll see where it says "No" & "Pending" on the 2 days. However, when I click view request, it's only showing the Pending record for Kelly. (Note, the 3 records at the very top are my test records, and it shows the dates that they should be assigned to)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzWCL.jpg

My block of code where the problem lies is as follows:

```
    foreach($events[$event_day] as $event => $value) {

    $calendar.= '<div class="event">';

    //Debugging
    $calendar.= '<pre>'. $value['status'] .'</pre>';

     $status = trim($value['status']);       



    //if ($inc < 1){
    $calendar.= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      View Requests
    </button>';
    //}
    $calendar.='<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align:center;">Agent Requests for - </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4" style="border-right:1px solid gainsboro;min-height:250px;text-align:center;"><span class="label label-success" style="font-size:14px;">Approved</span><hr/>';

    if ($status == 'Yes') {
        $calendar.= '<li>'.$value['title'] .' ' .$value['title2'].'</li>';
    }
    $calendar.='</div><div class="col-md-4" style="border-right:1px solid gainsboro;min-height:250px;text-align:center;"><span class="label label-danger" style="font-size:14px;">Denied</span><hr/>';
    if ($status == 'No') {
        $calendar.= '<li>'.$value['title'] .' ' .$value['title2'].'</li>';
    }
    $calendar.='</div><div class="col-md-4" style="text-align:center;"><span class="label label-warning" style="font-size:14px;">Pending</span><hr/>';
    if ($status == 'Pending') {
        $calendar.= '<li>'.$value['title'] .' ' .$value['title2'].'</li>';
    }
    $calendar.='</div></div></div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>';


    //End Event Div
    $calendar.= '</div>'; 


    }
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: Sorry i didn't read your question correctly i will delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're only seeing the first one is because your modal selector is using an id attribute `#myModal` which is supposed to be unique, so it stops looking after it finds the first one. Since you're outputting the modal content inside a foreach loop, then all the divs have the same id.

There's lots of ways to fix this, but I recommend using a unique id selector. You haven't provided any example data to work with, but I'm going to take a guess and assume you've got an `eventId` or something similarly distinct on the event data object. If you don't have a unique id, then you might get away with using the event name or something, but you should probably put an ID in there - especially if you're pulling from a database that you've designed.

Here's some abbreviated pseudo-code:

```
foreach($events[$event_day] as $event => $value) {
    // ...

    // get some sort of uniquely identifying data attribute from the event
    $eventId = trim($value['eventId']);

    // ...

    // uniquely select the modal content div with a distinct id
    $calendar.= '
        <button
            data-target="#myModal-' . $eventId . '"
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
            data-toggle="modal"
        >
        View Requests
        </button>';

    // ...

    // use this unique id when generating your modal content
    $calendar.='
        <div
            id="myModal-' . $eventId . '"
            class="modal fade"
            tabindex="-1"
            role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
        >';

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeff! I noticed that shortly after I wiped everything out and rebuilt it step by step. In addition, my order of operations was slightly off.

The Fix:

1.) Set Modal id's (otherwise it doesn't know which day to look at! Thanks Jeff.)

2.) Reorder Modal elements that shouldn't be repeated to be outside of the foreach loop.

Here is the corrected code:

```
$calendar.= '<div class="event">';

if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
            //Display Button if Data Present on Day
            $calendar.= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-'.$list_day.'">View Requests</button>';

            //Build Modal & Table Headers
            $calendar.='<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-'.$list_day.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel-'.$list_day.'">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel-'.$list_day.'" style="text-align:center;">Agent Requests for - '.$event_day.'</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                      <div class="row">
                                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                                                    <th>Agent Name</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Hours</th>

                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>';


            foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {

                //Start Table Row
                $calendar.='<tr>';

                    //Edit Button
                    $calendar.='<td style="text-align:center;"><a title="Edit Record" class="btn btn-default" href="edit-time.php?id='.$event['number'].'"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>';

                    //Status Indicator
                    $calendar.= '<td>'.$event['title'] .' ' .$event['title2'].'</td><td>';
                        if ($event['status'] == 'Yes'){     
                        $calendar.= '<span class="label label-success" style="font-size:14px;">Approved</span>';
                        }
                        if ($event['status'] == 'No'){     
                        $calendar.= '<span class="label label-danger" style="font-size:14px;">Denied</span>';
                        }
                        if ($event['status'] == 'Pending'){     
                        $calendar.= '<span class="label label-warning" style="font-size:14px;">Pending</span>';
                        }

                    //Hours
                    $calendar.= '<td>'.$event['hours'].'</td>';


                //End Table Row    
                $calendar.='</tr>';

                }
            //End Table Body & End Modal
            $calendar.='</tr></tbody></table></div></div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>';
        }
        else {
            //No Data
            $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);
        }

    //End Event Div
    $calendar.= '</div>';
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Best,
Will